# ReactJS: How to implement a simple 2D object movement along a path from start point to end point

Tags: reactjs, animation

[image]

I am working on a ReactJS project where I want to implement a simple 2D object (like the car) movement on the path. The scenario involves having a movable 2D object initially positioned on the starting point. Upon clicking the start button, the object should move on the path to reach the end point.

I'm just starting out with ReactJS and find myself a bit lost when it comes to creating stuff like this. If anyone could provide me with some beginner-friendly advice, step-by-step instructions, or even suggest resources that might help, I would be incredibly grateful. I'm eager to learn and any assistance would be a huge help. Thanks a bunch!

*P.S. The car should be on the starting point and not beside it.*

*P.S. I want to keep it simple without delving into complex 3D elements or using libraries like three.js. The goal is to achieve a straightforward effect as depicted in the above diagram.*

Comment: You're going to want math at some point, and the longer you hold off the harder this problem seems. You can simplify by restricting the axis, but at the end of the day you want the vector between the two points: `v = B-A` (which gives us direction + distance). From there you could divide the vector into the number of steps to take, or normalize it and multiply by the speed you want.

Comment: What do you seem to be lost at? Like maybe you can't find a good resource, is that it?

Comment: @coderboy Yes, that is the issue I'm facing. I'm new to animating elements, and I'm not sure where to find good beginner-friendly resources for creating simple animations like the one I'm trying to achieve. If you know of any tutorials or guides that cover the basics of animation, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you want a learning resource for React, I'd like to recommend this [beginner-friendly React course from Codeguage](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/react/). If you want a learning resource for 2D animations, then I'd like to recommend a few books to look into, but obviously only if you want to learn 2D animations.

Comment: By the way, the program that you're trying to create can be implemented using a simple CSS style like `transform: translateY(...)` or even `top`.

Comment: @coderboy Thank you! I tried implementing it myself after reading your answer, and it's working perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Aniket That's good to hear.